# Extract custom (angled) ROI from live stream image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a video stream from an IP camera and I need to process the specific region of interest (ROI) in the image (you can see in the screenshot).

The **problem** is that the camera is installed from the side and the images come with an angle. With `OpenCV` functions, I can only extract rectangle image. However, then I have unnecessary parts in the extracted rectangle. But, I want to extract custom ROI on this image and then process only this part. How can I achieve this?

[image: img1]

Below is extracted rectangle part of image (including unnecessary parts):

```py
upper_left = (0, 70)
bottom_right = (1280, 250)

    while True:
    success_1, img_1 = cam_capture.read()
    success_2, img_2 = cam_capture.read()

    if success_1 and success_2:
        # find difference between two frames
        diff = cv2.absdiff(img_1, img_2)

        # Rectangle marker
        r = cv2.rectangle(img_1, upper_left, bottom_right, (100, 50, 200), 5)
        rect_img = diff[upper_left[1]: bottom_right[1], upper_left[0]: bottom_right[0]]
```

Comment: what's the issue? how to apply a perspective warp?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, what do you mean exactly?